# JSOUP Cookie ID without post

Tags: java, android, post, get, jsoup

I'm creating an Android application which uses JSOUP to log into a website. In order to login I'm simply using the following:

```
loginDoc = Jsoup.connect(loginURL).get();
```

So this connects to the login URL which contains the users details. What I want to do is find out the session id (cookie data) for this session. How do I do this? As you can see i'm using a .get request and all of the examples I've seen on stackoverflow and elsewhere are using .post requests. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.get()` method returns a `Document`, but if you do an [`.execute()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#execute()) instead, you get a [`Response`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Response.html) object with the cookies, headers, et al.

For example:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl).execute();
String sessionId = res.cookie("sessionId");
Document doc = res.parse();
```

Comment: This makes complete sense, however, I get an error on "execute()" which says, cannot resolve symbol execute.

edit: I managed to resolve this by invalidating caches and restarting. Thanks

Comment: Ok it looks like it wasn't solved Lint was just disabled for some reason. So I'm still having that problem, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error. Maybe check your imports, and try compiling vs your linter? Here is an example that I just tested: https://gist.github.com/jhy/2be82da05b4b6be6dadd

Comment: Hi Johnathan,

Could you possibly check out my latest question? It's related to this one.